# How to find the closure of $M=\{(x,\sin(1/x))|x\in(0,1]\}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Hello I'm trying to find the closure of $$M=\{(x,\sin(1/x)|x\in(0,1]\}$$ I think the closure is $$K=\{(0,\sin(1/x))|-1\le \sin(1/x)\le 1\}$$ but I've no idea how to proof it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

For any $x\in[0,2\pi]$ consider sequences of the from $y_n=\frac{1}{x+2\pi n}$ that way $y_n\rightarrow0$ while any value between $[-1,1]$ gets covered

Comment: Thanks i figured it out!